# Running a thread on another machine

Tags: java, serialization, instructions

I have an application that runs on a low powered machine but requires logic that my low powered machine cannot handle. Is there a way for me to off-load that task to my other high powered machine?

Take the following:

```
class Example<T> implements Callable<T> {
    @Override
    public T call() {
        return SomeStaticUtilityClass.someIntensiveProcesss();
    }
}
```

Without Serialising the object, can I run the call() method on another machine?

If the answer is no; is there a way to copy the instructions required to execute the call() and send the instructions to my remote machine over a Socket to execute?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there are ways. Take a look at how Hadoop clusters operate. Basically it involves sending all required `.class` files to the execution node(s) and sending all required input, and all generated output, as serialized data.

Comment: I don't really want to send .class files because logic may contain code from dependencies (which can be 200mb sometimes). The dependencies may have been configured to work some sort of way too but I don't want to reconstruct it, I just want to run the heavy logic on another machine which has the resources to run the task. Is there a way to view the exact machine instructions of a function and pass that down to be executed?

Comment: If the class file with your code depends on 200mb of code, then your "exact machine instructions" also depend on a similar amount of code. Otherwise, your .class file doesn't really depend on that amount of code, Restructure your modules so that the code that actually has to run remotely has a smaller size. Otherwise, no, there is no way to pass the machine instructions to another machine. Unless you want to go and modify the JVM and make that feature yourself (which will take many man-years, most likely)